# Replace only a part of the string in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table with a nvarchar column having DateTime data in `YYYY:MM:DD HH:MM:SS` format. I want to convert and update this data into `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` format.

The problem i am facing is, If i use `REPLACE`, all `:` gets replaced by `-`, something like `YYYY-MM-DD HH-MM-SS` format.

How can i achieve this?

Existing data : `2016:10:27 15:39:33`

Desired data format after `REPLACE`: `2016-10-27 15:39:33`

EDIT :
I forgot to mention that the column has data in other DateTime formats too, like

- `YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM:SS`
- `DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS`

Comment: Alter the column to a proper date/time type.

Comment: @jarlh I assume / hope that this issue is coming from the wish to convert the existing values into properly typed values :-)

Comment: You got it right @Shnugo

Comment: is that all of the date time formats? or are there others? as this will need to be accounted for in any answers

Comment: @Tanner There are data in the desired `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` format too, apart from those mentioned in the post

Comment: @PrayagSagar I just updated my answer to convert all your formats properly...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
DECLARE @s VARCHAR(100)='2016:10:27 15:39:33'

SELECT REPLACE(LEFT(@s,10),':','-') + RIGHT(@s,9)
```

### UPDATE You found more different formats...

The following should convert them all

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(StringDate VARCHAR(100), RealDate DATETIME);
INSERT INTO @tbl(StringDate) VALUES('2016:10:27 15:39:33')
                                 ,('2016/03/23 12:33:44') 
                                 ,('2016-04-24 00:11:22') 
                                 ,('24/03/2016 11:22:33'); 

WITH Cut AS
(
    SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(LEFT(StringDate,10),':','-'),'/','-') AS DateString
          ,RIGHT(StringDate,8) AS TimeString
          ,RealDate
    FROM @tbl
)
,UpdateableCTE AS
(
    SELECT RealDate
          ,DateString
          ,CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('-',DateString,1)=5 
                THEN CONVERT(DATETIME,DateString + 'T' + TimeString,126) --ISO8601
                ELSE CONVERT(DATETIME,DateString,103) + TimeString END AS ConvertedDate
    FROM Cut
)
UPDATE UpdateableCTE SET RealDate=ConvertedDate;

SELECT * FROM @tbl
```

Answer (score 3):

As @jarlh wisely pointed out, you absolutely should avoid storing date information as `varchar`, for so many reasons.  You won't be able to take advantage of any of the power which SQL Server has for working with dates and timestamps.

But if you really just need to do this for formatting reasons, `STUFF` might come in handy:

```
SELECT STUFF(STUFF(col, 5, 1, '-'), 8, 1, '-')
FROM yourTable
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @a varchar(max) = 'YYYY:MM:DD HH:MM:SS'

SELECT 
  stuff(stuff(@a, charindex(':', @a),1, '-'), 
  charindex(':', @a, charindex(':', @a) + 1), 1, '-')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with multiple ways. My way with substring.

```
DECLARE @column1 varchar(max) = 'YYYY:MM:DD HH:MM:SS'
      SELECT
      REPLACE(SUBSTRING(@column1, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', @column1) - 1), ':' , '-') + ' ' +   SUBSTRING(@column1, CHARINDEX(' ', @column1) + 1, 8000)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample that handles your multiple date formats:

```
CREATE TABLE #Data
(
    date_strings NVARCHAR(20)
)

INSERT INTO #Data
        ( date_strings)
    SELECT N'2016:10:27 15:39:33'
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT N'1912:10:27 15:39:33'
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT N'20:11:2010 15:39:33'
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT N'12:10:1912 15:39:33'
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT N'2016-12-14 15:39:33'

SELECT  date_strings ,
    CASE 
      WHEN CHARINDEX(':', LEFT(date_strings, 10)) > 0
      THEN CASE 
            WHEN CHARINDEX(':', LEFT(date_strings, 10)) = 3
            THEN CONVERT(DATETIME, STUFF(STUFF(date_strings, 3, 1, '-'), 6, 1, '-'), 103)
            ELSE CONVERT(DATETIME, STUFF(STUFF(date_strings, 5, 1, '-'), 8, 1, '-'))
           END
        ELSE CONVERT(DATETIME,date_strings)
    END AS ConvertedValues
FROM    #Data

DROP TABLE #Data
```

This basically uses case statements to handle the dates in the different formats by looking for the position or presence of the `:` in the date portion of the value.

Case 1 - contains `:`:

```
CHARINDEX(':', LEFT(date_strings, 10)) > 0 -- needs conversion
```

Case 2:

```
CHARINDEX(':', LEFT(date_strings, 10)) = 3 -- formatted DD:MM:YYYY HH:MM:SS
```

Case 3:

```
formatted YYYY:MM:DD HH:MM:SS
```

Case 4:

Simply convert it, it's already in the correct format.

Note, the basic `STUFF`, syntax was taken from [Tim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40282021/57475).